# Respond on callback

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have 3rd party library, which is developed in C++. My C# app calls different functions from this library. Results of functions are returned through callbacks. The app has 4 layers: View-VM-BusinessLayer-ServiceLayer. In service layer I create instance of 3rd party object and call its functions. SL is singleton. Here is snippet of code

**SL:**

```
public Task<bool> InitializeAsync()
{
    OnConnectionStateChangedEventHandler connectionStateChangedEventHandler = null;
    OnBootCompletedEventHandler bootCompletedEventHandler = null;

    if (_coreObject == null)
        _coreObject = new CoreObject();

    _coreObject.OnBootCompleted += bootCompletedEventHandler;
    _coreObject.OnConnectionStateChanged += connectionStateChangedEventHandler;

    ....
}
```

**BL:**

```
ublic class LoginBusinessLogic : ILoginBusinessLogic
{
    public Task<LoginResult> LoginAsync(string server, string userName)
    {
        try
        {
            var address = Common.Helpers.CreateAddress(userName, server);
            return CoreService.Instance.InitializeAsync(address);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //TODO: Log exception
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**VM:**

```
var result = await _loginBusinessLogic.LoginAsync(Server, UserName);
```

I need to respond on events (OnBootCompleted, ect.) of core object in VM. I tried to use TaskCompletionSource, but the idea of this is, you call something and wait on event, after event is finished, you set result. But I need to be subscribed on the events whole application life. So I was thinking about event forwarding. But I'm not sure, if it's good solution.

Comment: Way too broad a question. If by "event forwarding" you mean to declare events in the service and business layers that allow the view model to effectively subscribe to the lowest-level events (i.e. through the business layer and in turn through the service layer), then yes...that should be fine. But it's not really clear that's what you mean, and if you're not sure it's a good solution, it's not clearly why. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a precise explanation of why that doesn't work for you.

Comment: I would like to respond in VM on event raised in SL.